# R Plot that shows how many User% did Postings%

Tags: r, plot, percentage

Hi everyone i have a question about plotting in R.

I need a line plot that shows how many %users wrote which %postings. 
Example would be: 25% of users wrote 80% of postings 

[image: graph]

Dput output:
[data](https://justpaste.it/1iw0f)

[image: data]

I read the data into R from csv and attached it with the headers.
Now when i try to plot it with: 
    `plot(UserPc,PostingsPc,ylab = "Users", xlab= "Postings",type="l")`

the plot is just a black square, halp

Comment: Please provide your data in a format that's easy to get into R (e.g. a data frame or a `dput`) and also reproducible code... right now, I can't regenerate the black square plot because I don't have your data structures. If you can, I think I can help you with this... there's a special kind of chart that does something close to what you want. Thanks :)

Comment: link to my csv file: http://www.sharecsv.com/s/0db74612eb2d1405475225f1cab1851c/data.csv  use MyData <- read.csv(file="data.csv", header=TRUE, sep=";")
attach(MyData) to read it. then u can try the plot from my question

Comment: That CSV is corrupt -- what we need is for you to edit the question so that it provides all data and code and that it's reproducible. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: i used dput on my data since it is so much i used a pateshare service (will link it in the question too) "https://justpaste.it/1iw0f"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UserPc` and `PostingsPc` cointain "," and "%" so `read.csv` interprets them as strings (which it reads as factors) rather than numbers. You'll see this if you run `str(myData)`. If you want to plot them, you need to convert them into numbers, which looking at your data requires replacing "," with "." and removing the "%". `gsub` is a useful function for this, and it's convenient to make the whole operation its own function. Something like this:

```
MyData <- read.csv(file="data.csv", header=TRUE, sep=";",stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
#write a function that removes all "%" from a string converts "," to "." and returns a numeric
#divide by 100 because it's a percentage
convert <- function(stringpct){
  as.numeric(gsub("%","",gsub(",",".",stringpct)))/100
}
MyData$UserPc <- convert(MyData$UserPc)
MyData$PostingsPc <- convert(MyData$PostingsPc)
attach(MyData)
plot(UserPc,PostingsPc,ylab = "Users", xlab= "Postings",type="l")
```

Comment: that helped alot thank you :) i did the changes with % and , to . in excel, now everything works fine thanks alot